# Draw on canvas with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas

I want to adapt a selection with rectangle (made with JS and html) in VueJs.
I have this version:
https://codepen.io/sebastiancz/pen/mdJVJRw

```
initDraw(document.getElementById('canvas'));

function initDraw(canvas) {

    function setMousePosition(e) {
        var ev = e || window.event; //Moz || IE
        if (ev.pageX) { //Moz
            mouse.x = ev.pageX + window.pageXOffset;
            mouse.y = ev.pageY + window.pageYOffset;
        } else if (ev.clientX) { //IE
            mouse.x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            mouse.y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
    };

    var mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0
    };
    var element = null;

    canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        setMousePosition(e);
        if (element !== null) {
            element.style.width = Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
            element.style.height = Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
            element.style.left = (mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
          console.log(mouse.x, mouse.y)
            element.style.top = (mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
        }
    }

    canvas.onmousedown = function (e) {

            console.log("Start.");
            mouse.startX = mouse.x;
            mouse.startY = mouse.y;
            element = document.createElement('div');
            element.className = 'rectangle'
            element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
            element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
            canvas.appendChild(element)
        }
  canvas.onmouseup = function (e) {
            element = null;
    // canvas.ctx.clearRect();
            console.log("finsihed.");

  }

}
```

and this is my non working version version in vue :
https://codepen.io/sebastiancz/pen/mdJPvOP?editors=0011

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something that you can do with Vue.js and HTML5 Canvas. You can further expand this to show previous selections by creating an array and storing start and end positions of the selections.

```js
Vue.component("selection", {
  template: `<canvas id='canvas' ref='select' @mousedown='startSelect' @mousemove='drawRect' @mouseup='stopSelect'></canvas>`,
  data() {
    return {
      ctx: null,
      selectionMode: false,
      startPosition: {
        x: null,
        y: null
      }
    };
  },
  
  methods: {
  
    startSelect(e) {
      this.selectionMode = true;
      this.startPosition.x = e.clientX;
      this.startPosition.y = e.clientY;
    },
    
    drawRect(e) {
      if (this.selectionMode) {
        console.log(this.startPosition);
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.rect(
          this.startPosition.x,
          this.startPosition.y,
          e.clientX - this.startPosition.x,
          e.clientY - this.startPosition.y
        );
        this.ctx.closePath();
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = "#f00";
        this.ctx.stroke();
      }
    },
    
    stopSelect(e) {
      this.ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

      this.selectionMode = false;
      this.startPosition.x = null;
      this.startPosition.y = null;
    }
    
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.select.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.$refs.select.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.ctx = this.$refs.select.getContext("2d");
    // this.ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    hello: "world"
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
  background: #eee;
}

#canvas {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <selection></selection>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: How can I do for remove the rectangle when I release the mouse button ?

Comment: @TheDevGuy If you wish to remove the rectangle upon release, you could add this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) in stopSelect method.